# bitfinex api, multiple orders, rest api, JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Пытаюсь создавать ордеры на bitfinex, через их REST API.
Все команды проходят нормально, только с Multiple New Orders (https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/order/new/multi) возникают непонятные проблемы.
В ответ на запрос не приходит ничего - пустая строка. Кроме "400 Bad Request" добиться ничего не получается. 
При этом сам сервис так же ни как не реагирует. 
От меня уходит JSON строка:

> {"request":"/v1/order/new/multi","orders":"[
>   {["symbol":"LTCUSD","amount":"0.2","price":"130","exchange":"bitfinex","side":"sell","type":"exchange
>   limit"]},
>   {["symbol":"LTCUSD","amount":"0.3","price":"130","exchange":"bitfinex","side":"sell","type":"exchange
>   limit"]}]", "nonce":"20171203002030019"}

Подозреваю, что дело в ошибке внутри массива. Хотелось бы взглянуть на "рабочую" строку данной команды, гугл не помог.

Comment: Для js в доках есть пример кода: https://bitfinex.readme.io/v1/reference#rest-auth-multiple-new-orders сверьте его со своим.

Comment: Валидатор https://jsonlint.com/ говорит что ошибка Error: Parse error on line 3:
... "orders": "[ {[" symbol ":" LTCUSD "
---------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']', got 'undefined'

Answer (score 0):

Писал на Delpi через JSONObject и JSON Array. 
Они строят строку из вопроса. Ошибка, собственно, в "[ и ]" при обозначении массива.

Comment: @Артем, не уверен - это ответ (проблема была в [])? Или это дополнение к вопросу, и вы все еще ищете решение?